# Arduino Uno R3 ISR does not work on pin 2?

Tags: arduino-uno, interrupt, isr

I have an Arduino Uno R3. I have a paddlewheel waterspeed sensor that I use on an ISR on pin 2. The power supply is approximately 8v stepped down to 4.92v with a circuit yanked from the phone charger. I have also tried this with the arduino 5v.

The pin returns the correct values with digitalRead(), so it's cycling between 1 and 0.

The ISR works fine on pin3. Why does it work on pin 3 and not pin 2 ISR?

```
void itest() {
    Serial.println( "test" );
}

void setup() {
    attachInterrupt(0, itest, FALLING);
}
```

Comment: Have you compared the disassembled code when using each pin?

Comment: Can you show us the code of the ISR and how you registered it?

Comment: Where do you set `pinMode()` of pin 2 to INPUT?

Comment: @jfpoilpret it doesn't need pinMode() and the ISR is hidden by the arduino code in the attachInterrupt

Comment: I hope you haven't forgotten to change `attachInterrupt(0,itest,FALLING);` to `attachinterrupt(1,itest,FALLING);`

Answer (score 3):

never use Serial inside an interrupt handler, increment a (volatile) variable and print it in the loop().